# Mui v5 DataGrid custom filter lost focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I added a custom filter in the datagrid to add a predefined value to the filters, the issue is when I try to select a value, the panel filter closes immediately after the menu is mounted.
the issue video [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B2Jp.gif)

I used the same example in mui v5 but I faced the issue. [ex](https://codesandbox.io/s/329hp?file=/demo.js:2151-2158)

```
function VisibilityValue(props) {
  const { item, applyValue, focusElementRef } = props;

  const ratingRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useImperativeHandle(focusElementRef, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      ratingRef.current
        .querySelector(`input[value="${item.value || ""}"]`)
        .focus();
    },
  }));

  return (
    <Select
      label='visibility'
      ref={ratingRef}>
      <MenuItem value='public'>Public</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value='private'>Private</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  );
}
```

This is to custom the operator:

```
 const visibilityOperators = [
    {
      label: "=",
      value: "equal",
      getApplyFilterFn: (filterItem) => {
        if (
          !filterItem.columnField ||
          !filterItem.value ||
          !filterItem.operatorValue
        ) {
          return null;
        }

        return (params) => {
          return params.value === filterItem.value;
        };
      },
      InputComponent: VisibilityValue,
      InputComponentProps: { type: "string" },
    },
  ];
```

DataGrid column:

> ```
> {
>       field: "visibility",
>       headerName: i18n.t("mom.res_confidentiality", "Confidentiality"),
>       flex: 1,
>       align: "center",
>       headerAlign: "center",
>       filterOperators: visibilityOperators,
>     },
> ```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, 
please add more details: What are you trying to achieve? Should the 'visibility' filter have a default value of "any" or a preselected value (public or private)?
you posted a link to a code sand box with a rating example, that does not match your example code. Do you want to achieve the same as the "isAdmin" filter? which is working by default, btw.  Are you also setting a filterModel to the data grid like in the sandbox example? If yes, please show that code, too.

Comment: Hi, first I added video to explain the issue, I'm trying to add custom drop down to the filter, drop down contains "Secret" also, so "isAdmin" example doesn't work in this case, and may I will use autocomplete in the filter so I need to fix this issue first.
I hop that was clear

Comment: I found this attribute "valueOptions", but I need to get full access on the filter component, so I can do my own code in the component

Comment: I watched the animated gif. It says: "Ten, Twenty, Thirty" in the dropdown before it disappears. It does not match your hardcoded values "Public, Private". What should be the displayed options and default value? Please update your question for clarity. If you want full control, you need to set a filterModel to datagrid, which is not shown in your code.